# Play Framework - only getting file content from Ok.sendFile(file)

Tags: scala, playframework

My users need to download a file when hitting a certain controller in my Play application. I thought this would do the trick:

```
def downloadFile = Action {
  Ok.sendFile(new File("example.zip"))
}
```

But it seems to only give the actual content of the file instead of downloading the file. Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the REST client we are using is automatically converting the file straight into its content instead of letting us download the file. Hitting it from a normal browser works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
def index = Action {
  Ok.sendFile(
    content = new java.io.File("/tmp/fileToServe.pdf"),
    fileName = _ => "termsOfService.pdf"
  )
}
```

Its from the documentation itself.

> Now you don’t have to specify a file name since the web browser will
>   not try to download it, but will just display the file content in the
>   web browser window. This is useful for content types supported
>   natively by the web browser, such as text, HTML or images.

See this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaStream

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Turns out my problem was that the REST client I am using was trying to be too smart. If I hit it directly it does download the file, the REST client was displaying the content of the file instead of letting me actually download it.